# Visual studio 2008 problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-plugin, visual-sourcesafe-2005

i am using visual studio team system 2008 and VSS 2005. I took a latest copy of a project from VSS. Now when i try to open that project, it is showing error

> "This version of visual studio does
>   not support source control"

and

> " Unexpected error enocountered.
>   Restart the application Error : no
>   such interfaces are supported File :
>   vsee\internal\vscomptr.inl".

When i open solution explorer, all projects are showing as unavailable. I tried

> VS-->Tools-->options--> source
>   control-->plugin selection

and set plug in to Microsoft "Visual source safe" and when i open "Environment" tab it is showing

> "an error occured while loading this
>   property page"

Can someone help me???

Answer (score 1):

Got it...... Yipppieeeeee    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952102

Answer (score 0):

VSS? Just say no. Not helpful, I know.

I'd start with deleting all the VSS files in the project folder, opening the project inside VS 2008, and then rebinding.

Comment: but wat about that plugin issue i have mentioned at the bottom of the question?will i b able to connect to VSS from VS once that problem persists?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. What my suggestion is doing, is eliminating one point of failure (which could be a result of upgrading from 2005 to 2008).